# Changing the np array does not change the Torch Tensor automatically?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch, tensor

I was going through the basic tutorials of PyTorch and came across conversion between NumPy arrays and Torch tensors. The documentation says:

> The Torch Tensor and NumPy array will share their underlying memory locations, and changing one will change the other.

But, this does not seem to be the case in the below code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((3,3))
b = torch.from_numpy(a)

np.add(a,1,out=a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

In the above case I see the changes automatically reflected in the output:

```
[[2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]]
tensor([[2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

But same doesn't happen when I write something like this:

```
a = np.ones((3,3))
b = torch.from_numpy(a)

a = a + 1
print(a)
print(b)
```

I get the following output:

```
[[2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]]
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, any time you write an equals sign in Python you are creating a new object. So the right-hand side of your expression in the second case uses your original `a` and then evaluates to a new object, which replaces this original `a`. `b` still points to the memory location of the original `a`, but now `a` points to a new object in memory.

Comment: That may very well be the case. Thank you; also is there any other way except using `np.add()` that can help me verify your explanation?

Comment: `a += 1` should do it.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that worked! thanks a lot! would you please explain how this is different from `a = a + 1` I was under the impression that both mean the same.

Comment: In `a = a + 1`, the expression `a + 1` creates a new array, and then *Python* assigns that new object to the name `a`.  With `a += 1`, Python calls `a`'s in-place addition method (`__iadd__`) with the argument `1`, and the numpy code takes care of adding that value to the existing array in-place.

Comment: Okay, I get it now! This is something I totally missed all these days learning python. Thanks again.

Comment: Please consider writing this as a separate answer to the question, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time you write a `=` sign in Python you are creating a new object.

So the right-hand side of your expression in the *second case* uses the original a and then evaluates to a new object i.e. `a + 1`, which replaces this original a. b still points to the memory location of the original a, but now a points to a new object in memory.

In other words, in `a = a + 1`, the expression `a + 1` creates a new object, and then Python assigns that new object to the name `a`.

Whereas, with `a += 1`, Python calls `a`'s in-place addition method (`__iadd__`) with the argument 1.

The numpy code: `np.add(a,1,out=a)` , in the *first case* takes care of adding that value to the existing array in-place.

(Thanks to [@Engineero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464597/engineero) and [@Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) for pointing out these explanations in the comments)

Comment: Very well explained! Thank You.